# Download and write image data in Julia

Tags: download, png, julia

I'm using the `get` function in the Julia `Requests` package (https://github.com/loladiro/Requests.jl) to download files. Some of the files are PNG images, and when I write the data in the returned object to a file:

```
x = get("url here")
outfile = open("file.png", "w")
write(outfile, x.data)
close(outfile)
```

...it does write the data to the file, but when I try to open it as an image, I get a file corruption warning.

It seems like `get` isn't downloading the file as binary, because when I download the file using the R function `download.file()` and the `mode="wb"` (write-binary) argument, I get different data in the file, and it opens successfully as an image.

Anyone have a good idea for how to download the PNG data correctly, or binary data in general?

Answer (score 3):

The `Requests` package exhibits strange behaviour for me, where `get`ting the same URL multiple times results in different `data` lengths, usually much shorter than the file. Anyhow, the `HTTPClient` package seems to work for me:

```
using HTTPClient
png = get("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png")
outfile = open("file.png", "w")
write(outfile, png.body.data)
close(outfile)
```

(Julia also has the convenience function `download(url, filename)` for this special case.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I get the following error: `ErrorException("error compiling get: error compiling setup_easy_handle: could not load module libcurl: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n")`. Is this a Windows-specific issue? I have the HTTPClient and LibCURL packages installed.

Comment: I honestly don't know, I don't use Windows. That said, I've had various compilation issues with other Julia modules on Linux and OS X, usually some random reinstalling has fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `download` and the `HTTP.jl` package, the `pwd()` is there to download the file to your local directory

```
using HTTP
HTTP.download("https://www.someURL.JPG",pwd())
```